# Cythonizing and importing cythonized files in profiler/cmd-line not working since Python 3.6.2

Tags: python, cython, python-import

I've been using the Spyder profiler quite a lot to profile my script. Today I updated to Anaconda 4.4 with Python 3.62 and Spyder 3.2.1, all running on 64bit.
My cythonized functions, can be imported in the Spyder editor and the IPython console easily. Running my script in the editor or using the IPython console works as expected.

But when I try to profile my script in the Spyder profiler OR try to run it in cmd `python "path/to/my/file/script.py"`, I get an `ModuleNotFoundError`.
Before updating to Python 3.6.2 it was working fine. The only way I can use my `Cython` functions now is to use `pyximport`, which I like for debugging but not for ready-to-use functions...
Another problem since the upgrade is that I can't run my `Cython` `setup.py` script anymore. It finished without generating any file and the command line shows no response like *Code generated* (or whatever it was) when invoking `setup.py`.

Has there been any change in Python/Cython implementation concerning importing Cython files? Or perhaps is there perhaps any package that I forgot to update/install? I followed the complete Cython install routine after the update, but no change...

edit: oh and btw... `__init__.py` is added in the relevant path and all relevant paths are also permanently added to `sys.path`.

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: You're missing most of the details needed to provide any real help, but: from about Python 3.2 compiled modules have a version number in their filename to help avoid silent incompatibilities between Python versions. This most likely means you'll have to recompile your modules with Python 3.6.

Comment: Thanks, good to know that I'll have to recompile it anyway. Unluckily I can't compile with setup.py and distutils anymore. On monday I'll ne back at work and adding more information. Which additional information would be needed?

Comment: I think initially: the exact command you're running to run setup.py, any output you get from it (try adding a `--verbose` option to increase the output you get). If it looks like a particular file is causing an issue then that file.

Comment: I'm running my setup.py with `python "path\setup.py" build_ext --inplace --verbose`. But still I got no output, nothing... So I commented out every line in my pyx-file and only left `from distutils.core import setup;
from Cython.Build import cythonize` in setup.py and ran it again. No it produced an empty file and printed "Finished generating code". Uncommenting all again so that my pyx and setup.py are completely back to the original state, it is compiling!! Don't know what happened here, perhaps some caching issue. Thanks for help!